# Subscribing on topic. MQTT

Tags: java, mqtt

I have the following part of code:

```
    package com.company;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main implements MqttCallback {
    private static String sTopic;
    private static int iQos;
    private static MqttClient mqttClient;
    private static String sUsername;
    private static Frame frame = new Frame();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MqttException {

        frame.getConnect().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int iPort;
                String sIp = frame.getBrokerAddressValue();
                sUsername = frame.getUsernameValue();
                try {
                    String broker = "tcp://"; //bridge and host
                    iPort = frame.getPortValue();
                    broker+=sIp+":"+iPort;
                    mqttClient = new MqttClient(broker, sUsername, new MemoryPersistence());  //URI, ClientId, Persistence
                    MqttConnectOptions connectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
                    connectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
                    System.out.println("Connecting to broker: "+broker);
                    mqttClient.connect();

                    System.out.println("Connected");
                }catch (NumberFormatException exc){
                    System.out.println("Wrong port format");
                } catch (MqttException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        frame.getSubscribe().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sTopic = frame.getTopicValue();
                try {
                    mqttClient.subscribe(sTopic);
                } catch (MqttException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Subscribed");
            }
        });

        frame.getPublish().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String sMessage = frame.getMessageValue();
                MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(sMessage.getBytes());
                iQos = frame.getQosValue();
                message.setQos(iQos);
                try {
                    mqttClient.publish(sTopic,message);
                } catch (MqttException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Message published");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception{
        frame.getTextArea().setText(String.valueOf(message));
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

    }
}
```

Here's a part of my realization of the mqtt client. Method getConnect is processing a click on button 'Connect', method getSubscribe is processesing a click on button 'Subscribe', method getPublish is processing a click on button 'Publish'.The problem is the following: when I subscribe on the topic, messages don't arrive on the clients, which are subscribed on this topic. What's the matter?

Comment: subscribing is not the same as publishing....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ,yes,I know. I have two methods: one for publishing and one for subscribing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly,You are subscribed to a topic  'sTopic' but you are not receiving messages when some one publish message to the topic 'sTopic'.

Are you sure Mqtt client is connected successfully to broker ?  Make mqtt client is connected before making subscribe call.

```
            if( mqttClient.isConnected()) {
                mqttClient.subscribe(sTopic);
             }
```

and same applies for publish also.

```
               if( mqttClient.isConnected()) {
                   mqttClient.publish(sTopic,message);
                }
```

Once if these call goes, you should see published messages in messageArrived call back method.

You need to set the callback method to mqttClient

```
                clientCallback = new MqttCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

                    }
                };

                mqttClient.setCallback(clientCallback);
```

Comment: Yes, you understood me right. I used in debugger and yes, client is connected in all cases. I probably think that there's the problem in publish method. I saw some examples of clients and there is the same line in all of them: client.setCallback(this); But I don't know how to add it to my project, as arguement 'this' is always underlined and writes that setCallback
(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback)
in MqttClient cannot be applied
to
(anonymous java.awt.event.ActionListener)

Comment: yes, now it works, thanks. So, as I understand, there's no need in connectionLost, messageArrived and deliveryComplete methods in the end of the class?